# Recognised Graduate visa (subclass 476) and iBT for Australia?

Tags: visa, australia, ielts, language-test, toefl

This is a statement from [this](http://www.immi.gov.au/Visas/Pages/476.aspx) page:

> ..., you must achieve a score of at least 6 in each of the four
>   components of the International English Language Testing System
>   (IELTS) **or another language test** and score specified by the Minister
>   for Immigration and Border Protection.

What does it means with "or anther language test"? Is TOEFL acceptable as well?

Comment: Isn't TOEFL more of a qualification for the teacher rather than the student?

Comment: @Gagravarr No it's not.  Test Of English as a Foreign Language is for stundents for sure.  http://www.immi.gov.au/students/english-requirements.htm

Comment: Ah, Test Of English vs Teaching (Of) English, the fun of acronyms...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Effective 18 April 2015](http://www.visahelpaustralia.com/news/changes_in_english_language_test_scores_for_the_skilled_-_recognised_graduate_subclass_476_visas), the Department of Immigration and Border Protection (DIBP) have reduced the English Language test scores and also accept all of the following language tests.

```
IELTS: International English Language Test System
OET: Occupational English Test
TOEFL iBT: Test of English as a Foreign Language internet-based test
PTE Academic: Pearson Test of English Academic
CAE: Cambridge English: Advanced (*test taken on or after 1 January 2015)
```

Answer (score 2):

While there is information on the [Student Visa](http://www.immi.gov.au/students/english-requirements.htm) that TOEFL is accepted as a substitute for IELTS.  The Work visas don't provide similar information.

The only reference to the alternatives I was able to find is on the [application for class 476 visa itself](http://www.immi.gov.au/students/english-requirements.htm)

Item 24 "Language Requirements" contains the following text:

> You are using International English Language Testing System (IELTS)
>   test or Occupational English Testing (OET) test results as evidence
>   of your English language ability – provide below the Test Report
>   Form (TRF) Number or OET test report that is included on your IELTS
>   certificate/OET certificate

So the best I can figure [OET](https://www.occupationalenglishtest.org/) would be the only viable alternative to IELTS unless the ministry can confirm otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

English test score other than IELTS are usually only accepted for student and working holiday visas. 476 is not a student visa. The statement "or another language test and score specified by the Minister for Immigration and Border Protection" is confusing at best. In practice the department will accept the OET, but only for specific occupations.

Taking the IELTS is you best bet to satisfy the eligibility for this visa.

From the page you mentioned, there are also some special cases:

For this visa you need an IELTS score of least 6 in each of the four components, unless you are a citizen of the United Kingdom, Canada, New Zealand, the United States of America or the Republic of Ireland

> English language ability
>
> If you are a citizen of the United Kingdom, Canada, New Zealand, the United States of America or the Republic of Ireland or you hold a valid passport from one of those countries, you are considered to meet the English language requirement for this visa.
>
> Otherwise, you must achieve a score of at least 6 in each of the four components of the International English Language Testing System (IELTS) or another language test and score specified by the Minister for Immigration and Border Protection. You must complete your test before you apply. From 1 July 2012, the score must be from a test that you sat no more than three years before you apply.
>
> The IELTS has an academic test and a general training test. You need only take the general training test.

Comment: Thanks. But currently I have TOEFL score above the required minimum. I need to know what is  " or another language test"?

Comment: What is the above required minimum of TOEFL for this visa?

Comment: http://ets.org/toefl/institutions/scores/compare